# System.ArgumentException in print screen function

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, screenshot

I'm using this function in my project to print a part of the screen :

```
public static Bitmap PrintArea(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
   int width = x2 - x1;
   int height = y2 - y1;
   var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

   // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
   using (Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(x1, y1, 0, 0, new Size(width, height));            
   return bmpScreenshot;
}
```

I'm calling this method in my main class in while loop and disposing the
returned Bitmap after using it each time, but after a while I get

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.

on `gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen()`. I searched for the problem in Google and i found some topics saying that `CopyFromScreen` has a memory leak.
How can I fix it ? should I do some updates for my .Net to fix that ? or there is another way to take a part of the screen ?

Comment: start by assuming you made a mistake, assume the error means what it says. What params are you passing to CopyFromScreen? What are the x1,y1,.... values? did u check in a debugger?

Comment: Yes I checked them and there are no mistakes on the parameters.

Comment: Why are you assigning gfxScreenshot twice over? The second time seems safe (in the using), but I'm not seeing where the first instance is getting disposed. I think lose the first assignment altogether

Comment: Thanks for pointing on that @Biscuits, i edited my code, I just made an error while copying my code.

Comment: Ok. It's hard to tell if your values for x1, y1, etc. are correct without seeing what the calling code is passing to your method. I would start by debugging to see what the values are. I'm beginning to think this is not a memory leak - especially if it already doesn't work the first time around.

Comment: I'm quite sure its not problem of my values, the program works fine for about 1 hour and a half and after that I get that error. I'll debug my program again and I'll put my values once I get that error again.

Comment: Here are the values I got from debugging : x1 = 840, y1 = 424, x2 = 952, y2 = 456, width = 112, height = 32.

Comment: Did you check if Bitmap is not also IDisposable?

Comment: No, How to check that ?